# Track memory allocation per function

Tags: c++, c, profiling

So I know I can track memory allocation with methods of overloading new globally like so: http://www.almostinfinite.com/memtrack.html

However, I was wondering if there was a good way to do this per function so I can get a report of how much is allocated per function. Right now I can get file and lines and what the typeid is as in the link I provided but I would like to find which function is allocating the most.

Comment: May be a good memory profiling tool provides this (not sure, if valgrind allows to do so).

Comment: I dont really want something as heavy as valgrind because then timing information is useless during that run

Comment: Yes, may be better to find some profiling tool based on code injection.

Comment: @mockinterface you obviously didn't read what I linked or the question I understand I can overload new but I want per function granularity and there doesn't seem to be a good way of doing that

Comment: Why not use valgrind?

Comment: And I see you also didn't read the comment 2 above your original one

Comment: There is nothing about "timing" requirements in your question, so it's best to specify that. Otherwise valgrind remains the valid answer.

Answer (score 2):

What about doing something like:  http://ideone.com/Wqjkrw

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

class MemTracker
{
    private:
        static char func_name[100];
        static size_t current_size;

    public:
        MemTracker(const char* FuncName) {strcpy(&func_name[0], FuncName);}
        static void inc(size_t amount) {current_size += amount;}
        static void print() {std::cout<<func_name<<" allocated: "<<current_size<<" bytes.\n";}
        static void reset() {current_size = 0; memset(&func_name[0], 0, sizeof(func_name)/sizeof(char));}
};

char MemTracker::func_name[100] = {0};
size_t MemTracker::current_size = 0;


void* operator new(size_t size)
{
    MemTracker::inc(size);
    return malloc(size);
}

void operator delete(void* ptr)
{
    free(ptr);
}


void FuncOne()
{
    MemTracker(__func__);

    int* i = new int[100];
    delete[] i;
    i = new int[200];
    delete[] i;

    MemTracker::print();
    MemTracker::reset();
}

void FuncTwo()
{
    MemTracker(__func__);
    char* c = new char[1024];
    delete[] c;
    c = new char[2048];
    delete[] c;

    MemTracker::print();
    MemTracker::reset();
}

int main()
{
    FuncOne();
    FuncTwo();
    FuncTwo();
    FuncTwo();
    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
FuncOne allocated: 1200 bytes.
FuncTwo allocated: 3072 bytes.
FuncTwo allocated: 3072 bytes.
FuncTwo allocated: 3072 bytes.
```

Comment: Hmmm this is interesting, however if you run the FuncTwo() multiple times you can see that it doesn't grow by a constant value as it should in that case because nothing is changing so it doesn't seem accurate. Also is `__func__` standard?

Comment: Also this requires users to add the global_alloc make pair stuff manually I was hoping for something that was automatic

Comment: http://ideone.com/Wqjkrw  would do.. I tried to make it automatic by making it reset and print in the destructor but it messes up for some reason.. This is probably the best I can come up with.. Other than that, you might have to actually download a memory profiler.

Comment: There isn't any real way for this to be automatically included in all functions though is there? The reason I say is that if i replace new globally i can choose to remove it at any point by removing the overloading for the new function or add it back if I want it. With this there is always that object included taking up memory.

Answer (score 0):

What platform are you using? There might be platform specific solutions without changing the functions in your code base.

If you are using Microsoft Visual Studio, you can use compiler switches /Gh and /GH to let the compiler call functions `_penter` and `_pexit` that you can define. In those functions, you can query how much memory the program is using. There should be enough information in there to figure out how much memory is allocated in each function.

Example code for checking memory usage is provided in this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682050%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I need something cross platform